# How to handle NaNs in binary variables (0 & 1) for Random Forest?

Tags: python, pandas, binary, nan, random-forest

I want to predict churns using random forest in Python. I got only binary variables (0 & 1), but the majority of the variables contain up to 60% missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill the NaNs with `-1`. That way the model can treat them specially, as the Random Forest model is based on decision trees it can handle this situation easily.

Replacing with zeros is not an option because you would be mixing the actual `0` values with the missing data (think that if you replace the missing data with zeros the model will no longer have a way to distinguish between which of them were zero and which ones were actually missing data). Replacing with an extreme value is the best, that way the model can use the fact that there is a missing value as extra information.